# Which verb should be used with self-control?

Tags: word-choice

So I know that one *loses* self-control, but what if you mean to say that someone is responsible for that? Which verb would be OK to use?

Perhaps:

> You **disturb** my self-control.
>   You **shake** my self-control.
>   You **take** my self-control.
>   You **vex** my self-control.

I can't find any instances of the first or last and only a couple of the second example. I found a lot of accounts using *take,* but it's part of a song so that taints the results. What sounds most natural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of your examples, *disturb* and *shake* seem most natural. *Take* sounds incorrect and *vex* is usually applied to people, not virtues. We usually talk about a *test of self-control* (or a *test of willpower*), so I would choose *test*, *strain*, or *try*.

Comment: ‘Take’ sounds incorrect? Tell that to Laura Branigan—in fact, perhaps because of the fame of that song, that was the one that sounded most natural to me (and the one I thought of before even opening the question). ‘Disturb’ and ‘shake’ sound fine, too, of course, but less final than ‘take’: if your self-control is disturbed or shaken, you still have self-control, just less of it. If it is taken, you have no self-control left at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I’d never heard the song, so maybe we’re both biased. *Take* makes sense, thinking about it, but it sounds more like a poetic version of “make me lose” than something you’d use in conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps: You **tax** my self control.

Answer (score 1):

You can **apply** some self-control
You can **lose** your self-control
You can **exercise** some self-control

Answer (score 0):

You can say, “You **make me** lose my self-control.”

Comment: ok but let's say that's not an option... is there another verb that could fit?? thanks